# Output wave of diode clamping circuit

Tags: diodes

In a positive clamping circuit in the first negative half cycle the capacitor charges then they say it functions as voltage source

I have a doubt the capacitor will discharge eventually then how can it function as a constant voltage supply

Comment: All caps have a T=RC discharge time, so a diode clamp requires periodic refresh or an AC signal to be DC clamped, like TV horizontal sync

Answer (score 1):

The capacitor is repeatedly recharged on every negative half-cycle.

It will discharge slowly on each positive half-cycle, so it isn't quite a constant voltage supply.